# Further problems with the monoid type class

Tags: haskell, monoids

I am trying to toy around with monoids using the `Semigroup` typeclass, and I am trying to define a monoid on the natural numbers. I put the following class and instance declarations into GHCI

```
Prelude:{
Prelude| class Semigroup a where
Prelude|    (<>) :: a -> a -> a)
Prelude| newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
Prelude|     deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
Prelude| instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
Prelude|    (<>) = coerce ((+) :: a -> a -> a)
Prelude| instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
Prelude|     mempty = Sum 0
Prelude| :}
```

I receive the message:

```
<interactive>:7:4: error:
Ambiguous occurrence ‘<>’
It could refer to either ‘Prelude.<>’,
                         imported qualified from ‘Prelude’
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
                      or ‘<>’, defined at <interactive>:3:4
```

I then entered `import qualified Prelude as P`, so as to avoid the clash, but this does not work, and I get the error message:

```
code<interactive>:26:19: error:
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Monoid’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘P.Monoid’ (imported from Prelude),
  ‘P.Monad’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: You should *not* define the typeclass yourself. It is already defined, by defining another one, it means that all your `(<>)` functions, etc. now can point to the `Semigroup` *you* defined, or the one that was defined in the prelude.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: sorry, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: the class declaration of `Monoid` exists already, in the `Prelude`. Hence by defining another one, it is ambiguous to what `Monoid` you are referring, the one you defined in the shell? Or the one that was imported from the `Prelude`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* define the typeclass yourself. It is already defined, by defining another one, it means that all your `(<>)` functions, etc. now can point to the `Semigroup` *you* defined, or the one that was defined in the `Prelude`.

You thus can define your type and make it an instance of `Semigroup` and `Monoid` with:

```
import Data.Semigroup

newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Num a => Semigroup (Sum a) where
    Sum a <> Sum b = Sum (a + b)

instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
    mempty = Sum 0
    mappend = (<>)
```

If we thus run this in the shell, we get:

```
Prelude> import Data.Semigroup
Prelude Data.Semigroup> :{
Prelude Data.Semigroup| newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
Prelude Data.Semigroup| 
Prelude Data.Semigroup| instance Num a => Semigroup (Sum a) where
Prelude Data.Semigroup|     Sum a <> Sum b = Sum (a + b)
Prelude Data.Semigroup| 
Prelude Data.Semigroup| instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
Prelude Data.Semigroup|     mempty = Sum 0
Prelude Data.Semigroup|     mappend = (<>)
Prelude Data.Semigroup| :}
Prelude Data.Semigroup> Sum 0 <> Sum 1 <> Sum 4 <> Sum 5
Sum {getSum = 10}
```

Comment: Why do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsp5pJlw6R0 (at 14:31) use the function ``coerce`` if it is not necessary to define a monoid on the natural numbers? I initially included ``coerce`` because that was what they did in their video.

Comment: @user65526 `coerce` is an advanced tool that automatically adds/removes the `Sum` data constructor as needed to make the expression to type check. Essentially, it turns `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` into `(+) :: Num a => Sum a -> Sum a -> Sum a`. If you are a beginner, it's best if you first learn how to do everything manually, using pattern matching (or `getSum`) and applying `Sum` as needed, without relying on too much automatic magic.